# validation: exists two column same request

Tags: php, laravel

I have in users table `email & phone` columns  I need to check in validation exist of both in one request like this:

```
$request->validate([
   'emailOrPhone' => 'required|exists:users,email,phone'
]);
```

When I request this validation I got this error:

```
"message": "Undefined array key 1",
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can reach it by  making it like that

```php
$request->validate([
   'emailOrPhone' => ['required',Rule::exists('users','email')->where('phone',$request->emailOrPhone)]
]);
```

Comment: Sir this solution does not work, I got error always even the email exists in DB